# Time Saver on Summary Stats

Tags: r, loops, knitr, summary, xtable

The goal is NOT cross tabulation. I am aiming for a table with descriptive statistics (in this case, counts & percentages) for all the variables in a dataset so that I do not need to type table(name of variable) approx. 20 times while working on a new dataset. I plan on just exporting this using xtable + knitr. Unfortunately, there is something wrong with the loop.  Any help would be appreciated. This question is very relevant to people who repeatedly need to present summary statistics as this would save a lot of time. Sorry for asking this a 3rd time :) **I have heard of the table() function - in fact, I've used it several times below** In a nutshell, this function presents the names of variables, their levels, the counts & percentages without making someone type in table() for each variable in a dataset-

```
ESRD <- rep(c("Y", "N"), each=10)
DIABETES <- rep(c("Y", "N", "Y", "N"), c(5, 5, 5, 5))
BLAH <- rep(c("Y", "N"), each=10)
categoricalvariables <- data.frame(ESRD, DIABETES, BLAH)

descriptives <- function(VARIABLEMATRIX){
desc <- matrix(0, ncol=4, nrow=2*ncol(VARIABLEMATRIX) + ncol(VARIABLEMATRIX))
  for (i in 1:ncol(VARIABLEMATRIX)){
    matper <- matrix(0, nrow=dim(table(VARIABLEMATRIX[ ,i])), ncol=1)
    for (i in 1:dim(table(VARIABLEMATRIX[ ,i]))){
      matper[i, ] <- paste(round(prop.table(table(VARIABLEMATRIX[ ,i]))[i]*100, 2), "%")
    }

    matcount <- matrix(0, nrow=dim(table(VARIABLEMATRIX[ ,i])), ncol=1)
    for (i in 1:dim(table(VARIABLEMATRIX[ ,i]))){
      matcount[i, ] <- table(VARIABLEMATRIX[ ,i])[i]
    }

    desc[((3*i)-2), ] <- c(colnames(VARIABLEMATRIX)[i], "", "", "") 
    desc[((3*i)-1):(3*i), ] <- cbind("", names(table(VARIABLEMATRIX[ ,i])), matcount[ ,1], matper[ ,1])
return(desc)
}
}
descriptives(categoricalvariables)
```

The output I am getting is (clearly there is a bug but I am not sure what is wrong):

```
     [,1]       [,2] [,3] [,4]  
 [1,] "0"        "0"  "0"  "0"   
 [2,] "0"        "0"  "0"  "0"   
 [3,] "0"        "0"  "0"  "0"   
 [4,] "DIABETES" ""   ""   ""    
 [5,] ""         "N"  "10" "50 %"
 [6,] ""         "Y"  "10" "50 %"
 [7,] "0"        "0"  "0"  "0"   
 [8,] "0"        "0"  "0"  "0"   
 [9,] "0"        "0"  "0"  "0"
```

The expected output should be:

```
     [,1]       [,2] [,3] [,4]  
 [1,] "ESRD"     ""   ""   ""     
 [2,] ""         "N"  "10" "50 %" 
 [3,] ""         "Y"  "10" "50 %"   
 [4,] "DIABETES" ""   ""   ""    
 [5,] ""         "N"  "10" "50 %"
 [6,] ""         "Y"  "10" "50 %"
 [7,] "BLAH"     ""   ""   ""     
 [8,] ""         "N"  "10" "50 %"  
 [9,] ""         "Y"  "10" "50 %"
```

Comment: Take a look at the summary and describe methods in pkg: Hmisc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some options using `tidyverse` functions:

```
library(tidyverse)

categoricalvariables %>% 
  gather(Measure, Value) %>%
  group_by(Measure, Value) %>%
  tally %>%
  mutate(Percent=n/sum(n))
```

> ```
>    Measure Value     n Percent
> 1     BLAH     N    10     0.5
> 2     BLAH     Y    10     0.5
> 3 DIABETES     N    10     0.5
> 4 DIABETES     Y    10     0.5
> 5     ESRD     N    10     0.5
> 6     ESRD     Y    10     0.5
> ```

```
categoricalvariables %>% 
  gather(Measure, Value) %>%
  group_by(Measure, Value) %>%
  tally %>%
  mutate(Percent=n/sum(n)) %>%
  gather(Stats, Value2, -Measure, -Value) %>%
  unite(Value_Stats, Stats, Value) %>%
  spread(Value_Stats, Value2)
```

> ```
>    Measure   n_N   n_Y Percent_N Percent_Y
> 1     BLAH    10    10       0.5       0.5
> 2 DIABETES    10    10       0.5       0.5
> 3     ESRD    10    10       0.5       0.5
> ```

I've left the data in numeric format in case you want to do further processing.

To set things up for an exported table, maybe something like this:

```
tab = categoricalvariables %>% 
  gather(Measure, Value) %>%
  group_by(Measure, Value) %>%
  summarise(Count=n()) %>%
  mutate(Percent=paste0(sprintf("%1.1f", Count/sum(Count)*100),"%")) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(Measure = ifelse(duplicated(Measure),"", Measure))
```

> ```
>    Measure Value Count Percent
> 1     BLAH     N    10   50.0%
> 2              Y    10   50.0%
> 3 DIABETES     N    10   50.0%
> 4              Y    10   50.0%
> 5     ESRD     N    10   50.0%
> 6              Y    10   50.0%
> ```

Now you can run `xtable` on `tab`.

```
library(xtable)

print(xtable(tab, align="llcrr"), include.rownames=FALSE)
```

Which looks like this when output from an `rmarkdown` document to PDF:

[image]

If you have numeric columns that you want to summarise, you can do, for example (using the built-in `iris` data frame):

```
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(mean, min, max)) %>%
  gather(key, value, -Species) %>%
  separate(key, c("Measure","Stat"),"_") %>%
  spread(Stat, value)
```

You'd probably want to reshape this further or reformat for output to a table, but it gives you an idea of what's possible.

> ```
>       Species      Measure   max  mean   min
> 1      setosa Petal.Length   1.9 1.462   1.0
> 2      setosa  Petal.Width   0.6 0.246   0.1
> 3      setosa Sepal.Length   5.8 5.006   4.3
> 4      setosa  Sepal.Width   4.4 3.428   2.3
> 5  versicolor Petal.Length   5.1 4.260   3.0
> 6  versicolor  Petal.Width   1.8 1.326   1.0
> 7  versicolor Sepal.Length   7.0 5.936   4.9
> 8  versicolor  Sepal.Width   3.4 2.770   2.0
> 9   virginica Petal.Length   6.9 5.552   4.5
> 10  virginica  Petal.Width   2.5 2.026   1.4
> 11  virginica Sepal.Length   7.9 6.588   4.9
> 12  virginica  Sepal.Width   3.8 2.974   2.2
> ```

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The `oway_tables` function in `descriptr` package creates multiple one way tables. Below is the output for your example:

```
> ESRD <- rep(c("Y", "N"), each=10)
> DIABETES <- rep(c("Y", "N", "Y", "N"), c(5, 5, 5, 5))
> BLAH <- rep(c("Y", "N"), each=10)
> categoricalvariables <- data.frame(ESRD, DIABETES, BLAH)
> descriptr::oway_tables(categoricalvariables)

                           Variable: ESRD                                
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                Cumulative                    Cumulative  |
|    Levels    |  Frequency   |   Frequency  |   Percent    |    Percent   |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|       N      |      10      |      10      |      50      |      50      |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|       Y      |      10      |      20      |      50      |      100     |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|


                         Variable: DIABETES                              
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                Cumulative                    Cumulative  |
|    Levels    |  Frequency   |   Frequency  |   Percent    |    Percent   |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|       N      |      10      |      10      |      50      |      50      |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|       Y      |      10      |      20      |      50      |      100     |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|


                           Variable: BLAH                                
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                Cumulative                    Cumulative  |
|    Levels    |  Frequency   |   Frequency  |   Percent    |    Percent   |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|       N      |      10      |      10      |      50      |      50      |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|       Y      |      10      |      20      |      50      |      100     |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Link to the documentation of the function: [`oway_tables`](https://rsquaredacademy.github.io/descriptr/reference/oway_tables.html).

Comment: Very helpful as well. Thank you!